# How can I make a border only on one/two sides?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I got to make 4 buttons near each other, I've done it by grid, but I've asked to add borders at only one/two sides (like in the next screenshot)
[With borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FryMJ.png)

So far I've done that:
[Without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOGlT.png)

The code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="NavagtionButtons">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource NavagtionButtons}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Assets/donut-icon.png" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock Text="Donut" Margin="10,15,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>


    <Button Style="{StaticResource NavagtionButtons}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Assets\coffee-icon.png" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Coffe" Margin="10,15,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource NavagtionButtons}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" >
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Assets\schedule-icon.png" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock Text="Schedule" Margin="10,15,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>

    <Button  Style="{StaticResource NavagtionButtons}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Assets\complete-icon.png" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock Text="Complete" Margin="10,15,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>



</Grid>
```

So how can I add borders only on the sides he showed?

Comment: You can put your buttons inside `Borders` and set their `BorderThickness` like `1,0,0,0`.

Comment: Can you show me an example please?

Comment: `<Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="White"><Button .../><Border/>`

Comment: Another thing if you don't mind - If I make a nice template on the MainPage.Xaml but I have like 4 pages, how can program only on the remain space on those other 4 pages?

Comment: Do you mean template inheritance?

Comment: No, I made the 4 buttons on the top, but I got 4 pages - how can I view those 4 buttons on all the pages and program only on the space that got left, and how can I start at a page that isn't MainPage?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer this question. Maybe you should ask this question in another thread?

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me, can't open more then a thread a day :\